# .NET Core vs .NET Framework - Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an **ASP.NET Core** 3.1 web app.

This application needs to load and execute some code from a 3rd party .**NET Framework** dll.

Unfortunately, the 3rd party code seems to have a dependency (or something else?) on **System.ServiceModel**, and when I call the code from that DLL, it throws the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference
> assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be
> loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)

**To try it out in a simpler environment, I have created 2 identical console apps which call this 3rd party component**

- .NET Framework - works OK, no errors thrown
- .NET Core - same error is thrown

That leads me to believing that **something is problematic when I try to call this 3rd party .NET Framework code from .NET Core.**

I had a look into a couple of questions, but they are a bit different:
[Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167205/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-servicemodel-version-4-0-0-0)
[Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648647/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-version-4-0-0-0-culture-neutral-publi)
[Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207137/reference-assemblies-should-not-be-loaded-for-execution)

Any idea what can I do to make it run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it turned out to be quite simple!

I had to add a reference to `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` nuget in the .NET core application and it started to work all ok!

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this issue as well, what worked for us was to make sure that the RID (Runtime Identifier) was set to `win-x64` (or `win-x32`). However our stack was entirely .NET Core/Standard

In your case it is not generally possible to load a .NET Framework dll into the .NET Core runtime as the underlying changes are not backwards compatible. So **even if you are able to get it to load you will likely run into runtime exceptions or process crashes/failures.**

Comment: Thanks - actually, it was possible - see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot load .Net Framework DLL into .NET Core. You can use .NET standard DLL into .NET Core. Use .NET Standard DLL in it. Usually, the third party should provide a .net standard version of the code

Comment: I don't think that's true in general. Within the same project I am using another 3rd party .NET Framework assembly and that one works with no problems. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46394435/2892378